# deconstruct and reconstruct a pretrained network in pytorch

Tags: python, model, pytorch

I'd like to use the G network I've found here:
https://github.com/scaleway/frontalization/blob/master/network.py
With the point:
https://github.com/scaleway/frontalization/tree/master/pretrained/generator_v0.pt

I understand it is composed by an encoder (from image 128x128 to vector 512) and decoder (from vector to image).
I need exactly the opposite: from 512 vector to 128x128 and again vector

Can I easy invert encoder/decoder?
Can I use the weights in the pretrained point after the first operation?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution

First, I've created a new model class switching encoder and decoder

```
class G2(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(G2, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 4, 1, 0, bias = False), # Output HxW = 4x4
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, 2, 1, bias = False), # Output HxW = 8x8
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, 2, 1, bias = False), # Output HxW = 16x16
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 4, 2, 1, bias = False), # Output HxW = 32x32
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 4, 2, 1, bias = False), # Output HxW = 64x64
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, 4, 2, 1, bias = False), # Output HxW = 128x128
            nn.Tanh(),
            # Input HxW = 128x128
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 64x64
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 32x32
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 16x16
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 8x8
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 4x4
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 4, 2, 1), # Output HxW = 2x2
            nn.MaxPool2d((2,2))
            # At this point, we arrive at our low D representation vector, which is 512 dimensional.
        )
    
    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.main(input)
        return output
```

I've loaded the pretrained model and created an instance of the new one.

```
netG = torch.load('generator_v0.pt')
netG2 = G2()
```

And copied the layers (and pretrained weigths) (not sure that this is the "elegant" way)

```
for idx in range(len(netG2.main)):
    if(idx<17):
        netG2.main[idx] = netG.main[17+idx]
    else:
        netG2.main[idx] = netG.main[idx-17]
```

Thanks for your comments